# Oracle Stored Procedure to insert values from query, if values do not exist in target

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, insert

**Oracle stored procedure:** I want a stored procedure that inserts table and column names into another table (target: add_definitions). I want to be able to run this procedure at any time to pick up new tables/columns that may have been added to the database. Also, I only want to add items that belong to a specific owner (Oracle term - aka "PUBUSER"), and try to avoid "system" tables. The solution must be a stored procedure.

Current stored proc that does not work

```
create or replace procedure test_adding as
    sqlcmd varchar2(2000);

begin
    sqlcmd := 'insert into add_definitions (table_name, column_name) ' ||
      'select aa.table_name, aa.column_name ' ||
      'from all_tab_columns aa ' ||
      'where (instr(aa.table_name, ''$'') = 0 and aa.owner = ''PUBUSER'') and ' ||
      '(not exists (select item_id from add_definitions cc where cc.table_name = aa.table_name and cc.column_name = aa.column_name))';
    execute immediate sqlcmd;

end test_adding;
```

I checked the above by first manually populating the add_definitions table (with all the proper values). Then I deleted 2 of the rows. Then when I run the above, those 2 rows are not added back. I checked the SELECT part of the above INSERT and it does return the 2 items (table_name and column_name) that I deleted.

Note: I simplified the code, I need to add other values during the insert which get calculated from other code snippets (I plan on doing the "USING" part of the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE... to substitute those values into the sql command). But I cannot get this very basic step to work first. So please do not offer suggestions to "not do" a stored procedure, etc, etc. After 30 hours on this, I'm about to shoot myself.

**Update:** As per one of the comments, I tried to get this to run without EXECUTE IMMEDIATE - just did a direct "INSERT INTO... SELECT ..." It still failed to recover the deleted values (I retested the above steps over again, several times, using the direct INSERT approach). This is quite frustrating as one of the other responses says it works fine for them....??? (I'm using Oracle 11g Express Edition - but I sure hope that would not make a difference).

Comment: I don't see the need for dynamic sql here. why not simply run an `INSERT INTO SELECT * ` ?  Using dynamic sql makes it harder to debug the code because it turns compile time error to run-time error. So, use it only when absolutely needed.

Comment: Part of the other items that need to be added will come from user-supplied data passed into the stored procedure. So I'll eventually have to put things in to protect against SQL injection and so on. That is why I started with dynamic SQL. Are you suggesting that dynamic SQL is runs differently than straight SQL (apart from the debug features)?

Comment: I am just suggesting  to you to get your static sql(with simple insert) running first and then try to put it in a dynamic block. Whether you need dynamic sql depends on parameters you are going to use. If they are just values that you want to use in your insert statement, you may not need dynamic sql. if they are dynamic table names and column names or entire where clause, you may have to use it as there's no other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems no problem with your code, except not including and not populating `item_id` column in the insert statement :

```
SQL> create table add_definitions (item_id int, table_name varchar2(100), column_name varchar2(100));
SQL> create sequence seq_test start with 1;
SQL> create or replace procedure test_adding as
    sqlcmd varchar2(2000);
begin
    sqlcmd := 'insert into add_definitions (item_id,table_name, column_name) ' ||
      'select seq_test.nextval,aa.table_name, aa.column_name ' ||
      'from all_tab_columns aa ' ||
      'where (instr(aa.table_name, ''$'') = 0 and aa.owner = ''PUBUSER'') and ' ||
      '(not exists (select item_id from add_definitions cc where cc.table_name = aa.table_name and cc.column_name = aa.column_name))';
    --dbms_output.put_line(sqlcmd);
      execute immediate sqlcmd;
end test_adding;

SQL> exec test_adding; -- Assume 100 rows inserted

SQL> select count(1) from add_definitions;

  COUNT(1)
----------
       100

SQL> delete add_definitions where item_id in (99,100);  

SQL> select count(1) from add_definitions;

  COUNT(1)
----------
        98

SQL> exec test_adding; 

SQL> select count(1) from add_definitions;

  COUNT(1)
----------
       100             

SQL> commit;
```